# how to redirect console output to an object as a parameter

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, web-scraping

I have written a script that scraps google scholar and gets me the link to download the paper, but the problem is, it gives me in the console when the project is executed. I want that download link to store in an object and finally download it 
I want to store it in website object.! For now I just hardcoded the link from console and pasted it over here.!

```
URL website = new URL(" http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/421/1/1999-65.pdf");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\paper.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

And here is my whole scrapping code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?q=Sergey+Brin.+Extracting+patterns+and+relations+from+the+world+wide+web.+In+WebDB+Workshop+at+EDBT+%E2%80%9998%2C+1998.+Available+online+at+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwwwdb.stanford.edu%2F+sergey%2Fextract.ps%3E.&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
            .get();

    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);


    Elements links = doc.select("div.gs_ggsd").select("a[href]");
    //Element  = doc.select("div.gs_ggs gs_fl").first();

    for (Element link : links) {
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
    }
```

And here is the output in console I want  , ( I only need the link )

```
title : Sergey Brin. Extracting patterns and relations from the world wide web. In WebDB Workshop at EDBT %E2%80%9998%2C 1998. Available online at %3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwwwdb.stanford.edu%2F sergey%2Fextract.ps%3E. - Google Scholar

link : http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/421/1/1999-65.pdf
text : [PDF] stanford.edu
```

Comment: What's a website object?

Comment: an object holding the url to download a paper